# Html flag background

Tags: html, css, background

I'm trying to make an HTML CSS german flag background and it's kind of hard. I tried using before and after on the body and inside it putting a white section with 80% height and 50% width. It should be in the middle of the screen, so I did top 50%, left 50%, but it turned out really bad. The section is where all the articles shoud be so it's like white space with a z index bigger than the body so it's like white on the flag.

**UPDATE**

jsFiddle: http://goo.gl/aCjHnK

Comment: could you post some code? maybe use jsfiddle.com to show us what you have now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with ::before and ::after:

Verical stack:

```
#background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#background::before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 33.33%;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
}

#background::after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 33.33%;
    background: gold;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
}
```

Horizontal stack:

```
#background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: gold;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index:-1;
    left:0;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#background::before {
    content: '';
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
}

#background::after {
    content: '';
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution, which I think is more easy.
If you would like to achieve this with before and after, please show your code, so that we are able to help

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#black, #red,#gold {width: 150px; height:25px;}
#black{background: black}
#red{background:red}
#gold{background:gold}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="black"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="gold"></div>
</body>

</html>
```